# Add color to rows when a value is in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to figure out how to make numerous cells change color (red) when one cell has a value in it. Basically it is when money is owed I want the whole row to turn red so it stands out to me. I have it set right now that the cell with the money value turns red, but I want that whole row to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: When you say you have it setup so that the cell turns red, do you mean with conditional formating?

Comment: I believe so, I made it awhile ago.

Comment: If that is the case, simply change the range the rule `Applies to` so that all the cells you want highlighted are coloured red.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that I can change a range so that an entire row changes color due to the value of one cell.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example where only the cells in question get highlighted:

[image]

And here is one where the row gets highlighted:

[image]

Look at the difference in the `Applies to` columns, one reads `=$E$1:$E$14` and the other `=$A$1:$E$14`

Comment: I got it, it was my rule that was causing me the problem. Do you know how to duplicate that? Like if the column of E went down to E200 and I want them all to work the same?