# How to set the background colour of the rows in a spreadsheet depending on the value of a cell in the row

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

How can I say,in Excel on the web: If cell F2 contains "Completed", set the background colour of row 2 to red?

There are lots of articles online ([e.g.1](https://superuser.com/a/1322903/767863), [e.g.2](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/18/change-background-color-excel-based-on-cell-value/)) but they all seem to refer to desktop versions and require selecting Conditional Formatting → New Rule... .

My Excel on the web, part of Office 365, does not have a New Rule... command. I have a Manage Rules dialogue, but that only seems useful for deleting rules.

Comment: You can create the rule in Excel for Desktop and then upload the file to Excel online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The online version of Excel does have a Conditional Formatting button in the Home pane:

[image]

The method to use is very similar to that described for the Desktop version
in the articles you have linked to.

For a detailed description with screenshots, see the article
[How to Use Conditional Formatting in Excel Online](https://zapier.com/blog/excel-conditional-formatting/)

Comment: That's a great help, but your screen shot shows an option entitled `Highlight Cells Rules`. I can't find how to highlight the whole row.

Comment: The link has this: "You start out by selecting the cells to which the rule will apply. This might be your entire spreadsheet or just a selection of rows or columns."

Comment: Yes, you select a range. But Excel only highlights **Cells in the range**.

Comment: Accepted with a reservation. This seems to be the only method supported. I can't do the question in the title - set the colour of a whole row.